# fallback vars vaule inserts bracket

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, css-variables

i'm using in my project css vars with fallback values as other variables called defaults.

in chrome dev tools i saw in that var brackets.

this is a screen shot from dev tools: https://prnt.sc/m0n0xh

```
:root{
--hf-style: normal;
--hf-variant: bold;
--hf-size: 19px;
--hf-family: Titillium Web;

--header-font: var(--hf-style, var(--def-hf-style)) var(--hf-variant, var(--def-hf-variant)) var(--hf-size, var(--def-hf-size)) var(--hf-family, var(--def-hf-family));

--def-hf-style: normal;
--def-hf-variant: bold;
--def-hf-size: 18px;
--def-hf-family: Titillium Web;
--def-hf: normal var(--def-font-variant) var(--def-font-size);
}
```

everything works fine, but i wonder if it is correct and will not cause errors in the future

Comment: Since it's spec-compliant the only potential problem could be performance on a real page (now or in the future when it becomes more complex). You can test it in devtools performance timeline profiler and compare to a literal value.

Comment: How did you produce the screenshot? My Chrome doesn't have such a tooltip. I can look at Computed, and there it says `normal bold 19px Titillium Web` for the value of --header-font.

Comment: @MrLister i did use Lightshot application. In my chrome (latest version) there is a tooltip in `var(--arrow-bg)` when i focus the variable name